# Custom fields disappeared from wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have **custom fields** on my wordpress installation but after theme update, **they disappeared from admin**.
They still show the content on front-end, but I can't add new content from admin.
I already checked if it was unchecked in "screen-options", **but it isn't there** ...

**I tried to deactivate every plugin** and see if anything changed, but no.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version you had, I am using Wordpress 5.2+. I had the same problem, I can't find the checkbox of **Custom Fields** in the **Screen Options** as it suppose to be but later on I found it in the Options of adding or editing post. Go to **Posts** > **Add New** > click on 3 vertical **Dots** on the top right conner > click on **Options** > once the options dialog box popped up you will see **Custom Fields** checkbox under **Advance Panels**.

[image]

[image]